# Colocar uma classe do Bootstrap dentro de um formulário gerado com CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-3

Alguém sabe me dizer como chamo as classes do Bootstrap dentro de um formulário que gerei usando o CodeIgniter? Pelo que pesquisei usa-se um array associativo, mas não estou conseguindo. Por exemplo, no label quero colocar class='sr-only' e nos input class="form-control input-lg".

```
echo form_open('crud/create');
echo validation_errors('<p>','</p>');
            echo form_label('Nome Completo');
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'nome'), '','autofocus');
            echo form_label('Email');
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'email'));
            echo form_label('Login');
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'login'));
            echo form_label('Senha');
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'senha'));
            echo form_label('Repita a senha');
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'senha2'));
            echo form_submit(array('name'=>'cadastrar');
echo form_close();
```

Comment: Tentou colocar dentro da array? echo form_input(array('name'=>'email', 'class' => 'nomedaclass'));

Comment: No input dá, mas estou me complicando um pouco é no label.

Comment: Resolvi. Consegui usar o array associativo no label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do CI você deve criar um array com os atributos que quer adicionar da seguinte maneira:

```
$atributos = array (
'class' => 'sua class',
'style' => 'color: #fff;' );
// E assim por diante
```

E depois adicionar a variavel atributos dentro do seu `form_label` ou seja

```
echo form_label('Nome Completo', $atributos);
```

você pode ver mais detalhes na [documentação do CI](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_label)

Comment: Exato, Rafael, foi que percebi ao consultar a documentação.

Comment: Use desta maneira que te passei para o código ficar mais organizado @FernandaFerreira evite usar o outro método de colocar um array dentro do `form_label` além de estranho fica feio! rs

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver.

```
echo form_label('Nome Completo','',array('class'=>'sr-only'));
```